# How to play iOS SystemSound SoundID in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I would like to see a sample in c# (Xamarin.iOS) of how to play an iOS built in sound on my app.
First, does someone know if apple allows it (copyright issues)? And if so, How do I accoumplish it in Xamarin?

I saw the following sample in native iOS:
https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1003); // SMSReceived (see SystemSoundID below)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Staring at a native sample won't get you any further. ;-) A quick google returned: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SysSound

Comment: I saw this sample but I would like to play a system sound without having to bring the sound file into my app. Since the native way allows you to play a system sound by sound ID, I am wondering if It could accomplish the same in Xamarin.iOS. Based on the native sample, I tried to find the classes with similar names, but did not successed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To play predefined sounds, you first need the sound ID. A list can be found [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices).

Then it's almost the same as the native code:

```
using AudioToolbox;

var sound = new SystemSound(1100);
sound.PlaySystemSound();
```

Note that this will only work on a physical device but not in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Hi Krumelur, should it be able to work on the simulator eather?

Comment: Nope. Works on the device only.